# div tag problem

Tags: html, tags

in my website designing side i meet one problem , even now also i don't know how to rectify that problem. any one help me

```
 <div style="overflow:auto;height:535px; width:656px;position:absolute;" id="abit" runat="server"  >

contents...

</div>
```

in this code i got scroll bar. but i don't want that scrollbar, but i want that actions, how to do this?

advance thx...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. Perhaps you should try another value:

1. `overflow:scroll` - Scrollbar is always present.
2. `overflow:hidden` - Extra content is clipped with no scrollbar.

Or perhaps a few moments looking at the [other overflow options](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) would answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the css `height` property. The scrollbar might appear because the content is higher that what the div could handle.

Answer (score 0):

1) The scrollbar is appearing because the content of the div is larger than the fixed height of the div.

To get rid of the scrollbar, you can
1)Increase size of div
or
2)set style="overflow:hidden"
or
3)Remove the clamp you're setting, in other words, get rid of style="height:**px"